# Is there a way to make my dropdown menu appear on the Toplevel() window while it is outside the Toplevel() function?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my code, I am trying to make the dropdown menu appear on the second window I created. However, the dropdown menu keeps appearing on the main (root) window. I know there is a way to make it appear when it is inside the function where the second window is called for, but I want to know if there is a way to make the dropdown menu appear on the second window, when the variable for it is outside the function. I have tried to add a global variable but it did not work.

```
enter code here
from tkinter import *

newWindow = ''
def openNewWindow():
  global newWindow
  newWindow = Toplevel(root)

eventName = ["Lampada", "Trivia",]

root = Tk() #Creates a window with title bar
root.title("House Events") #Title bar name
root.geometry("535x250")

nextWindowButton = Button(root, text=">", command=openNewWindow)
nextWindowButton.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)

doneEvents = StringVar()

dropEvents = OptionMenu(newWindow, doneEvents, *eventName)
dropEvents.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are creating the OptionMenu at a point in time when only the root window exists - the user cannot possibly have clicked the Button yet, to create the new window.  You need to create the widget from within `openNewWindow()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this addresses your issue.

Create a new `OptionMenu` in `Toplevel` and use `global eventName` to pass data to it.

This will allow the actions in `Toplevel` to propagate to `OptionMenu` in `root` and vice versa.

```py
import tkinter as tk

eventName = ["Lampada", "Trivia"]

def openNewWindow():
    global eventName
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel()
    newWindow.transient(root)
    dropEvents = tk.OptionMenu(newWindow, doneEvents, *eventName)
    dropEvents.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)

root = tk.Tk() #Creates a window with title bar
root.title("House Events") #Title bar name
root.geometry("535x250")

nextWindowButton = tk.Button(root, text=">", command=openNewWindow)
nextWindowButton.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, sticky = tk.NSEW)

doneEvents = tk.StringVar()

dropEvents = tk.OptionMenu(root, doneEvents, *eventName)
dropEvents.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It makes sense to do it that way, but I am just looking for easier ways to structure my code better. I want to add multiple things in the second window so it will look messy to just have everything inside that function.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I was looking for thanks to the help from someone in another source. If I create the new window straight after creating the root window, I can use the ".withdraw()" and ".deiconify()" method to hide and reveal the window whenever I need it.

```
   from tkinter import *

   def openNewWindow():
     newWindow.deiconify() #Displays Window
     newWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", newWindow.withdraw)
  
   eventName = ["Lampada", "Trivia",]

   root = Tk() #Creates a window with title bar
   root.title("House Events") #Title bar name
   root.geometry("535x250")

   nextWindowButton = Button(root, text=">", command=openNewWindow)
   nextWindowButton.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)


   newWindow = Toplevel(root)
   newWindow.geometry("300x200")
   newWindow.withdraw() #Hides Window

   doneEvents = StringVar()

   dropEvents = OptionMenu(newWindow, doneEvents, *eventName)
   dropEvents.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

   root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way without using `deiconify()` and `protocol()`. Also no need declare `global`.

Modified code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() #Creates a window with title bar
root.title("House Events") #Title bar name
root.geometry("535x250")

doneEvents = StringVar()
 
def openNewWindow():
    newWindow = Toplevel()
    newWindow.title("Option Menu")
    newWindow.geometry("300x200")
    dropEvents = OptionMenu(newWindow, doneEvents, *eventName)
    dropEvents.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
     
  
eventName = ["Lampada", "Trivia",]

nextWindowButton = Button(root, text=">", command=openNewWindow)
nextWindowButton.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]